# Apache Thrift: Can we instruct thrift to translate a SET container to Java LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, thrift

From the documentation: Thrift translates a SET container to HashSet by default. Can we change this behavior?

Containers
Thrift containers are strongly typed containers that map to commonly used and commonly available container types in most programming languages.

https://thrift.apache.org/docs/types:

*There are three container types:
list: An ordered list of elements. Translates to an STL vector, Java ArrayList, native arrays in scripting languages, etc.
set: An unordered set of unique elements. Translates to an STL set, Java HashSet, set in Python, etc. Note: PHP does not support sets, so it is treated similar to a List*

Comment: I already know I can change the type to LinkedHashSet in the java class generated by thrift. But it is not useful in our case as we generate/replace thrift classes every time in our build process.

Answer (score 0):

**The `sorted_containers` option** switches to

- `TreeMap` for `map<>`
- `TreeSet` for `set<>`

The option is to be specified when calling the Thrift compiler, like so:

```
$ thrift  -gen java:sorted_containers  myfile.thrift
```

Here are **all options available for Java** (curent master branch, `thrift -help` reveals more info)

```
 java (Java):
    beans:           Members will be private, and setter methods will return void.
    private-members: Members will be private, but setter methods will return 'this' like usual.
    nocamel:         Do not use CamelCase field accessors with beans.
    fullcamel:       Convert underscored_accessor_or_service_names to camelCase.
    android:         Generated structures are Parcelable.
    android_legacy:  Do not use java.io.IOException(throwable) (available for Android 2.3 and above).
    option_type:     Wrap optional fields in an Option type.
    java5:           Generate Java 1.5 compliant code (includes android_legacy flag).
    reuse-objects:   Data objects will not be allocated, but existing instances will be used (read and write).
    sorted_containers:
                     Use TreeSet/TreeMap instead of HashSet/HashMap as a implementation of set/map.
    generated_annotations=[undated|suppress]:
                     undated: suppress the date at @Generated annotations
                     suppress: suppress @Generated annotations entirely
```

Other options are not available. The C++ generator supports annotations, this seems not to be the case with Java. Did I mention that [we accept patches](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute)?

Comment: @[JensG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499466/jensg), Similar to the sorted_containers option, is there a way where I can use ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap implementation? We need this to prevent null keys in the map.

Comment: [Link to source](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/compiler/cpp/src/thrift/generate/t_java_generator.cc#L4190) No, only what I wrote above. However, if you think that's a good addition and want to do it - we accept pull requests! The C++ generator has an option to specify classes via IDL annotations, maybe that could be a way to go. Questions? Mailing list!

Comment: @ [JensG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499466/jensg), can we have this option added for Java generator too?