# Custom container type in Apache Thrift

Tags: java, thrift, concurrenthashmap

How can I write a custom container type with Apache Thrift?

I am aware that, by default, any map declaration in Thrift extends HashMap.

Is there a way that I can modify it to extend ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap?

For e.g., if Test.thrift is defined as follows:

struct TestData
{
    1:  string id,
    2:  map details
}

How can I make sure that this map is implemented as a ConcurrentHashMap?

Thanks!

Comment: I read in another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341492/apache-thrift-can-we-instruct-thrift-to-translate-a-set-container-to-java-linke)  that we can use sortedcontainers which would use TreeMap implementation instead of HashMap while generating the java classes. Similarly is there any other option to use ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap while generating java classes using Thrift compiler?

Comment: What don't you understand at the answer given there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tree predefined container types (`list<R>`, `set<T>` and `map<K,V>`), which are tied to a suitable, language specific implementation.

While Thrift does enable you to freely construct `struct`s in a lot of ways, there is no extension to the basic **IDL data types** and containers.

Some language bindings, like C++, allow customisation of **container implementation** (i.e. which classes are actually used in the generated code) by means of IDL annotations. However, this is supported only with a small subset of the languages and AFAIK Java is NOT one of them.

> How can I make sure that this map is implemented as a ConcurrentHashMap?

You need to change the Thrift compiler or post-process the generated code artifacts somehow.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what we are currently doing - modifying the post process that generates the classes.